# Use Bash to merge column by column between two files

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Use Bash to merge column by column between two files

Hi all,

I have two files which i want to merge column by column in bash.  I have had a good look but cannot find an answer.  Below are example input files and a desired output.

```
file1.txt
A,S,G,S,G
K,A,G,A,G
K,S,A,S,A

file2.txt
K,S,B,S,G
K,S,G,D,G
K,S,G,S,E

expected-output.txt
AK,SS,GB,SS,GG
KK,AS,GG,AD,GG
KK,SS,AG,SS,AE
```

The sets of input files will have a variable number of fields and a variable number of lines (however these will always be the same within sets of input files)

Many Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried with paste, but cannot find a way to make it work column by column. 
 
I have tried with pr -mt but had the same problem.  

I saw a post to use awk '{print $1}' file1 file2, but this only printed the first file.

I could use a very convoluted use of cut and paste or awk, but i don't know how to specify for variable number of fields.
Cheers

Comment: Are the CSV fields always exactly 1 character wide?

Comment: yep, always 1 character per field

Comment: commonly there will be between 10-20 fields and around 8000 lines per input sets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generic solution and with N number of fields in Input_files following may work.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    array[FNR,i]=$i
  }
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    $i=array[FNR,i] $i
  }
}
1
' file1  file2
```

---

---

You could try following, for fun + written and tested with shown samples only, in case your real files are different then it may not work.

```
xargs -n5 < <(paste -d',' <(xargs -d',' -n1 < file1) <(xargs -d',' -n1 < file2)) |
awk '{gsub(/,/,"@");gsub(/ /,",");gsub(/@/,"")} 1' |
sed '$ d'
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder!  The awk worked beautifully and was nice and fast.  The xargs version seemed to leave some blank columns in places.

Comment: @jspudross, glad that it helped you, xargs version is very specific to your samples as mentioned, cheers and happy learning.